If $A$ and $C$ are dependent random variables, is $\mathsf E(AC|A=a)=a\mathsf E(C|A=a)$?
The title says it all.  I believe this expectation could be written as
$$
\mathsf E(AC|A=a)=\int ac f_{C|A}(c|a)\,\mathrm dc=a\mathsf E(C|A=a),
$$
which would then answer the question in the affirmative.

True even when density doesn't exist.

Can you claim this even if $a$ has the property $\mathbb P(A=a) = 0$?


Where $A=a$, there $AC=aC$.

Expectation is a Linear Operation, so constants may be distributed out.


$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(AC\mid A{\,=\,}a)&=\mathsf E(aC\mid A{\,=\,}a)\\[1ex]&=a\mathop{\sf E}(C\mid A{\,=\,}a)\\[4ex]\mathsf E(AC\mid A) &= A\,\mathsf E(C\mid A)\end{align}$$
